# How to generate buzzer at timer countdown?

Tags: java, android

I'm looking to play a sound when a CountDownTimer expires.  I can't seem to get it working as I want.  I've looked at some sample code using the ToneGenerator but it is not working as I'm expecting it to and because I'm new to android and java, not really sure how to get it working better.

Here is what I have:
- Countdown timer works.  It starts and stops when I click on it and resumes when I click on it again.  Everything is perfect here.

- I have managed to play some sounds out of my device but it will actually repeat for some reason.  Not sure why.

Here is what I want:
- onFinish() of the CountDownTimer, I would like to generate a tone around 2800Hz for a period of 2 or maybe 2.5 seconds.
- after I get it working, I would like to play with the idea of making it an alternating tone at say 2800Hz and 2000Hz for 50ms each or something and for a period of 2 to 2.5 seconds.

** EDIT **

```
public void soundBuzzer() {
    ToneGenerator toneGen;
    int type1, type2;
    toneGen = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);

    type1 = ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_6;
    type2 = ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_8;

    toneGen.startTone(type2, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code? If it's repeating there's something wrong.

Comment: If you just want to play a sound, you could use `MediaPlayer`. Generate the sounds externally and include them in your resources.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I didn't see the comments.  I will edit my post to add the code.  I don't know how to set the loop around it so I can alternate 20ms with type1 and type2.

Answer (score 0):

The ToneGenerator will generate a tone that sounds like the tone on a telephone when you hold down a number.  I was unable to get the buzzer to sound using that class and making it sound good.  As a result I ended up playing an MP3 for sound.

Here's the code:

```
// function to generate a tone for 3 seconds
public void soundBuzzer( boolean shortBuzzer ) {
    MediaPlayer mp;

    if( !shortBuzzer )
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(appContext, R.raw.buzzer_2s);
    else
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(appContext, R.raw.buzzer_short);

    mp.start();

}
```